# NSLocation location keep updating

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get the current location only once, but `didUpdateToLocation` is being called over and over. I'm calling `getCurrentLocation` in `viewDidLoad`. How can i only let it get the location once?

```
- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [storesArray count]-1; i++) {            
            CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
            CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];

            CLLocation *checkPosition = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

            CLLocationDistance distance = [checkPosition distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

            float distanceInKm = distance / 1000;

            if (distanceInKm > 5) {
                NSLog(@"%@", distanceInKm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `stopUpdatingLocation` when you've got what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

cf. [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopUpdatingLocation):

> Call this method whenever your code no longer needs to receive location-related events. Disabling event delivery gives the receiver the option of disabling the appropriate hardware (and thereby saving power) when no clients need location data. You can always restart the generation of location updates by calling the startUpdatingLocation method again.

Comment: Okay seem to work, but it's strange that i get 4 distance returned when the [storesArray count]-1 = 2. it should only return 3 distances

Comment: I have no idea what `storesArray` is. It's code you didn't share so how can we help with this? But you should probably call `stopUpdatingLocation` 1st thing in your implementation of `didUpdateToLocation` otherwise the latter is going to get called every time the sensor gets a more accurate position or the position changed significantly depending on how you configured the location manager.

Comment: It seem to still run the for loop twice why?

Comment: I think the 2nd part of my latest comment answers that. As long as the sensor gets location updates and you haven't called `stopUpdatingLocation`, `didUpdateToLocation` will keep being called.